# Как отсортировать 2 текстовых файла удалить несколько столбцов и объединить оставшиеся столбцы с помощью python

Tags: python

Есть 2 файла, надо из файла 1 удалить "столбцы"    MDI/MDIX, Port State, Speed/Duplex/FlowCtrl  и добавить из файла 2 столбец "Mac Address".

Результат должен быть примерно такой:
Port  speed/duplex            Mac Address
1     100M/Full/Disabled      11-CC-EE-99-EE-СС
2     100M/Full/Disabled      AA-BB-EE-CC-FF-22

Подскажите какой модуль для этого использовать, с чего начать? Мб у кого-то есть пример решения подобного рода задачи.

Файл 1
Port|Port   |Settings             |Connection        |MDI/MDIX
    |State  |Speed/Duplex/FlowCtrl|Speed/Duplex
1   |Enabled|100M/Full/Disabled   |100M/Full/Disabled|Auto
2   |Enabled|Auto/Disabled        |100M/Full/Disabled|Auto
3   |Enabled|Auto/Disabled        |100M/Full/Disabled|Auto

файл 2
VID  VLAN Name   MAC Address        Port  Type
1    default     00-33-7E-EC-D8-EF  26     Dynamic
1    default     04-11-39-CC-5C-86  20     Dynamic
1    default     DD-22-ED-AA-3A-81  26     Dynamic
1    default     11-CC-EE-99-EE-6B  8      Dynamic
1    default     11-CC-DD-AB-37-95  14     Dynamic
1    default     33-C7-FF-77-BB-58  9      Dynamic

Comment: Используйте pandas. приведите воспроизводимые примеры обоих файлов одинаковой размерности. а то у вас из первого файла только одна строка., а из второго - 7

Comment: Очевидно написать программу. Что вы уже сделали? В чём затруднения? Покажите код!

Answer (score 0):

Повторю рекомендацию strawlju - используйте *pandas*!  Там есть функция, специально предназначенная для ввода таких файлов:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('c:/data.csv', sep=',')
```

Она возвращает переменную типа DataFrame - проще говоря, двумерный массив. А сама библиотека *pandas* предоставляет средства для работы со строками и столбцами таких массивов. Удалить два столбца и добавить новый - всё очень просто.